# Python 3.6 iterating through list of dictionaries using filter() with lambda doesn't return dictionary's value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filter

There is a list of dictionaries I need to iterate through and filter in dictionaries which meet criterion and then return only values under key1. I'm using filter, as follows:

```
res = list(filter(lambda x: x["key1"] if ["key2"] == criterion else False, list_of_dicts))
```

the iterator works alright returning only those results which meet criterion. But it returns the whole dictionary rather than only `x["key1"]`.
I'm thinking it's something to do with filter but have no clue.

Q1: Can someone explain why it returns whole dict rather then only value under key1?

Q2: is there a workaround to make filter to return only value under key1?

P.S. there is no problem to do it through list comprehension like that:

```
res = [i["key1"] for i in list_of_dicts if i["key2"] == criterion]
```

But I was just curious why filter doesn't return `i["key1"]`.

Answer (score 7):

Filtering is *not the same thing as mapping*. Filtering *selects* based on your criteria, a yes/no decision on whether or not to include one of your values.

In fact, you are filtering on both `key2` *and the truth value of `key1`*; if the value for `key1` is ever set to `None` or `0` or another [false value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), you'd also drop that specific dictionary, which I don't think you really wanted.

You want to filter *and map*, so extract the right key from the dictionaries that passed the filter. That's actually best done with a list comprehension instead:

```
res = [x["key1"] for x in list_of_dicts if x["key2"] == criterion]
```

You can still do it using `filter()`, if you must, but then you need to add a `map()` call to this to actually do the mapping:

```
res = list(map(lambda x: x["key1"], filter(lambda x: ["key2"], list_of_dicts)))
```

But as you notice, that gets verbose and unreadable really quickly. You could use [`operator.itemgetter()` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to replace the `lambda`s:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = list(map(itemgetter("key1"), filter(lambda d: d["key2"] == condition, list_of_dicts)))
```

but readability doesn't improve much with that.

Comment: I am not so sure it's faster than the list comprehension, I've done a lot of tests with map vs list comprehension and only when the variable is very large does map edge ahead, although I can't speak for filter and itemgetter ._.

Comment: @new_to_coding: it is faster, because the list comprehension loop is executed entirely as bytecode interpretation steps, including the filter test and extraction expression. It is the combination of `itemgetter()` and `map()` and `filter()` here that is the real speed devil, *all of the execution* is done entirely in C code, outside of the interpreter loop.

Comment: @new_to_coding: I did make a mistake; the filter has to test for equality against a condition, at which point the performance boost is diminished.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for you response Martjin, it's very clear especially with map function. As Willem noted, filter returns an iterable. So, I was just wondering if iterable is returned why filter can't handle it just like it handles iterable object which it accepts in its constructor?

Comment: @Vlad: I'm not sure what you are asking. `filter()` is a very specific tool. It filters, it doesn't map as well. If you are asking why it can't return the same type of object that you handed it: because an iterable is an *interface*, and loads of different types can implement it. Not all of those can be recreated just like that, they all can have a different method of creation.

Answer (score 6):

A filter simply *filters*: it takes as input an iterable, and produces an interable with the items that satisfy the criterion.

What you want is an additional *`map`ping*:

```
from operator import itemgetter

key1 = itemgetter('key1')

res = list(map(key1,filter(lambda x: ["key2"] == criterion, list_of_dicts)))
```

Mind that you do not need to use `x['key1'] if ... else False` in the criterion: the `filter(..)` will simply evaluate the function, and inspect the *truthiness* of the result. If it is `True`, it will emit the item, otherwise it will ignore the item.

Comment: Thanks for the threory Willem! it makes sense now.